# Adjusting specular for a metal

Tags: shaders, reflection, pbr

As per [Principled shader docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html), Specular parameter controls dielectric specular reflection.

As I understand it, when I set metallic to 1., I only get the specular (tinted) reflection, and no diffuse reflection.

What does changing the specular slider do for the fully metallic material? Should I set it to 0. for a physically accurate metal?

Comment: Hi :). The whole 0-1 range is physically accurate and realistic. You can keep it at 0.5, which covers most materials. Alternatively go full *physics geek* and [use a specific IOR](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/05/blender-3d-tip-realistic-specular-value-in-principled-shader/) (probably an overkill) :))

Answer (score 4):

[image: Example of specularity]

The above image is inspired by a diagram on page 13 of Disney's *"Physically-Based Shading at Disney"*
["Brief note"](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58586fa5ebbd1a60e7d76d3e/t/593a3afa46c3c4a376d779f6/1496988449807/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf) about the original principled shader.

This was generated using a principled BSDF shader with everything except *Metalic* and *Specularity* set to default.  Metalic is set to 1 and specularity to the value above the sphere.

It's a very subtle effect, but the way the principled shader is designed, it is in effect using the IOR of a material to simulate the Fresnel effect.  It, in fact, implements a variant of the Fresnel equation to accomplish the transition between specular and diffuse.

Comment: So that's the picture, but what does it correspond to physically? Is specularity the portion of the light that gets reflected in a specular way? If so, why is the remaining one diffused if metals don't have a diffused reflection?

From the picture, it looks like it's defining whether the Fresnel effect is applied: does it mean only 1. is physically accurate?

Comment: @sygi Another explanation here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/155424/78972

Comment: CG does not use the terms 'diffuse' and 'specular' in precisely the same way as physics does and the principled shader uses 'specularity' in a very non-physics manner. At best it only approximates physics and you're close, it's defining how the Fresnel effect is applied through a formula that relates 'specularity' to an IOR value and uses that IOR value to calculate Fresnel.